# How can you tell when a Java import statement uses wildcard matching?

Tags: java, import

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171452/how-can-i-import-android-util-log-from-inetaddress-java-or-any-file-in-libcore) which is apparently a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147454/why-is-using-a-wild-card-with-a-java-import-statement-bad). I always thought that asterisks were the only way to denote wildcard matching in import statements.

What causes either of the import statements

```
import android.util.Log;
```

or

```
import android.os.Environment;
```

to be interpreted as patterns that could match multiple packages? Or is there some other definition of wildcard matching that I don't understand?

Please help!

Comment: The same way it would take google to auto fill your search when you type something in the search bar...An algorithm!!! :)

Comment: Sometime questions are closed for dumb reasons... SO users are humans.

Comment: For what it's worth your question has 2 votes to reopen it (I think 4 or 5 are required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I always thought that asterisks were the only way to denote wildcard matching in import statements.

They are.

> What causes either of the import statements `import android.util.Log;` or
>   `import android.os.Environment;` to be interpreted as patterns that could match multiple packages?

Nothing.  They are not.

> Or is there some other definition of wildcard matching that I don't understand?

Not per se.

But looking at your other question, it seems like the real problem is with the classpath that is being used when `InetAddress.java` is being compiled.